# Set directory for saving my result (report, log) in a specific folder before running robot framework script

Tags: report, robotframework

I want to save my results in a specific folder for each running in robot framework.
I know there is a command call `--outputdir` which I also use.
But I want to know if there is any possibility to set the path for saving my results before in the robot script?

Thanks.

Best
psad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.

The internal variables for paths are set as constants.

Also you should not have that approach because the test operations should be separated from the orchestration operations.